# Building an executable JavaFX app with java SDK 11.0.6

Tags: java, maven, javafx-11, jlink

I have a JavaFX app that I have successfully built and run with Java SDK 1.8.  I am trying to move it to Java 11 with an ultimate goal of using Java 14 and can not create a runnable jar.  To try and understand the process I have downloaded the javafx helloFX example and tried to follow the instructions at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular for Maven.  When I run the mvn clean javafx:jlink I get the error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------< org.openjfx:hellofx >-------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ hellofx ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\jungl\eclipse-workspace\helloFX\Maven\hellofx\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.3:jlink (default-cli) @ hellofx ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\jungl\eclipse-workspace\helloFX\Maven\hellofx\src\main\resources
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\jungl\eclipse-workspace\helloFX\Maven\hellofx\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.345 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-14T14:52:18+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.3:jlink (default-cli) on project hellofx: Error: jlink requires a module descriptor -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>hellofx</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>HelloFX</mainClass>
      <jlinkImageName>hello></jlinkImageName>
      <jlinkZipName>hellozip></jlinkZipName>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zenjava/javafx-maven-plugin -->
```

Can anyone point me in the correct direction as I am failing to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The provided example is not structured as the tutorial says.  The maven version has been updated under the CommandLine folder.  If you go to: ..\CommandLine\Modular\Maven\helloFX and enter the commands mvn clean javafx:run,  clean javafx:jlink, target\hellofx\bin\launcher it runs as described in the tutorial.